# Python TypeError: bind(): AF_INET address must be tuple, not str

Tags: python, sockets, web

I'm building a chat server for a school project, but when I ran the code I got this error:

> TypeError: bind(): AF_INET address must be tuple, not str

```py
import socket
import select

#server booting up with ip + port (server.bind) and listnes for new connections (server.listen) and printing in the and booting up to let the user know
server = socket.socket()
server.bind(("192.168.1.14, 4434"))
server.listen(5)
inputs = [server]
print("booting up the server...")

#notify for new connections
def notify_all(msg, non_receptors):
    for connection in inputs:
        if connection not in non_receptors:
            connection.send(msg)

#function that check for new connections and greets the new users + updating the amount of people connected to the server
def greet(client):
    names = [n.getpeername() for n in inputs if n is not client and n is not server]
    greetMsg = "hello user! \n users online:" + str(names)
    client.send(greetMsg.encode())

while inputs:
    readables, _, _ = select.select(inputs, [], [])
    for i in readables:
        if i is server:
            client, address = server.accept()
            inputs.append(client)
            print("connected to new client")
            greet(client)
            notify_all(f"client {address} enterd".encode(), [server, client])

        else:
            try:
                data = i.recv(1024)
                notify_all(str(str(i.getpeername()) + ">>>" + data.decode()).encode(), [server, i])

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                inputs.remove(i)
                print(f"client {i.getpeername()} BYE")
```

Answer (score 1):

`("192.168.1.14, 4434")` is exactly the same as `"192.168.1.14, 4434"` (without parentheses), which is a string. As the error message says, the argument to `bind` should be a tuple, not a string:

```
server.bind(("192.168.1.14", 4434))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is: `server.bind(("192.168.1.14, 4434"))`.

You pass it a single string of `"192.168.1.14, 4434"` instead of a tuple that contains two separate values.

You need to change it to: `server.bind(("192.168.1.14", 4434))`

Note that the port should be int, not str.